# Accessing variables outside of function with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter, global-variables

I'm building a simple app that requires two separate files to be read for which I have two functions. The functions just open a file explorer when a tk button is pressed.

For now, I just want to print the filename in the terminal with the end goal of using the file names to update tk labels and to be used in another function.

I've declared each file name as a global variable in both functions but I can't access them without calling the functions. If I call the functions, the file explorer window will open without the user pressing the buttons.

So I guess my question is, is there any way to access the global variables without calling the functions? Surely using the button calls the function which should make the global variable available?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os 
# Function for opening the
# file explorer windows

def browseFiles_csv():
    global filename_csv
    filename_csv = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.txt*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
          
    # Change label contents
    csv_label.configure(text="File Opened: "+ os.path.basename(filename_csv))
    return filename_csv

def browseFiles_cfg():
    global filename_cfg
    filename_cfg = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.txt*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
     
    # Change label contents
    cfg_label.configure(text="File Opened: "+ os.path.basename(filename_cfg))
    return filename_cfg 
                                                                                                
# Create the root window
window = Tk()
  
# Set window title
window.title('File Updater')
  
# Set window size
window.geometry("500x250")
  
#Set window background color
window.config(background = "white")
  
# Create a File Explorer label
csv_label = Label(window,
                            text = "Please select a  *.csv file",
                            width = 100, height = 4,
                            fg = "blue")

cfg_label = Label(window,
                            text = "Please select a *.cfg file",
                            width = 100, height = 4,
                            fg = "blue")
  
      
csv_button = Button(window,
                        text = "Select csv",
                        command = browseFiles_csv)

cfg_button = Button(window,
                        text = "Select cgf",
                        command = browseFiles_cfg)
  
button_exit = Button(window,
                     text = "Exit",
                     command = exit)
  
# Place controls
csv_label.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
csv_button.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
cfg_label.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
cfg_button.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
  
button_exit.grid(column = 1,row = 5)

#Using this code I get the file explorer opening before I use the select buttons
#fn_csv = browseFiles_csv()
#fn_cfg = browseFiles_cfg()

# Using this code I get errors with filename_xxx not defined though they are global variables
fn_csv = filename_csv
fn_cfg = filename_cfg

print(fn_csv)
print(fn_cfg)
  
# Let the window wait for any events
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Declaring a variable as global inside a function does not create the variable until the function is executed.  However you can initialize the variable outside the function.

Comment: In cases like this, I have found it useful to define one global variable for the whole program (e.g. `filenames`), which is a dictionary that can then store all the objects from different functions. You just initiate it as empty `dict` at the beginning of the program and fill it in your functions (e.g.: `filenames["CSV"]=...`). You can then access the names from all over your program.
(However, if your program gets any more complex, it would be a good idea to change your window into a custom class with methods. That's way more efficient)